# What is the equivalent of get_user_option for saving options?

Tags: options, user-meta

In a custom plugin, I want to save user interface settings (e.g. which sections are expanded/hidden).

From what I see, the `get_user_option` ([docs here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_option/)) function is perfect for retrieving the value.

However, I don't think there is an `add_user_option` or `set_user_option` function like I would have expected (following the logic of non-user-specific options).

Thus the question: what is the equivalent of get_user_option for saving options?

Is it `update_user_option` ([docs here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_user_option/))?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `update_user_option` to update user options.
Read more here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_user_option/